# C - Expected ")" before "*" in Binary Search tree

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I'm writing a binary search tree in c and I keep getting the silly "error: expected ')' before '*' token" message for the beginning of my functions in their declaration and in the header file..

main file

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "func.h"

#define ARRAYSIZE 12

int main(int argc, char *argv[3]) {

typedef struct node {
    int value;
    struct node * left;
    struct node * right;
}  * node;

node* root = NULL;

int nodes[ARRAYSIZE] = {3,6,2,1,7,8,3,5,7,2,9,4};
int i;

for(i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE; i++) {
    root = insert(root, nodes[i]);
}


if (strcmp(argv[1], "q") == 0) quit();
if (strcmp(argv[1], "i") == 0) insert(argv[2]);
if (strcmp(argv[1], "d") == 0) delete(argv[2]); 
if (strcmp(argv[1], "s") == 0) search(argv[2]);
if (strcmp(argv[1], "e") == 0) empty(); 

return 0;
}
```

functions file

```
    #include "func.h"


    node * createNode(int value) {
    node * new_node = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

    if(new_node == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }

    new_node->value = value;
    new_node->left = NULL;
    new_node->right = NULL;

    return new_node;
    }

     void insert(node * root, int n){
      if(root == NULL) {
    root = createNode(n);
    }
    else {
    int left  = 0;
    node * current = root;
    node * previous = NULL;

    while(current != NULL){
      previous = current;

      if((n == current->n) < 0) {
        left = 1;
        current = current->left;
      }
      else if((n == current->n) > 0) {
        left = 0;
        current = current->right;
      }
    }
    if(left)
        previous->left = createNode(n);
    else
      previous->right = createNode(n);
    }
    }

    void delete(node * root, int n){
     node *current, *parent, *successor, *presuccessor, q;

     if (root->left == NULL) {
        printf("\ntree is empty! (deleting)");
     }

     parent = root;
     current = root->left;

     while (current !=NULL && n != current->value) { 
            parent = current;
            current =  (n next) ? current->left : current->right;
        /* maybe add the } here ;) */

        if (current == NULL) {
          printf("\n %d is missing \n", n);
    }

     // Item found, now delete it

     if (current->left == NULL)
            q = current->right;
     else if(current->right == NULL)
        q = cur->left;
     else {
        // Obtain the inorder successor and its parent
        presuccessor = current;
            current  = current->left;
           while (successor->left != NULL) {
               presuccessor = successor;
               successor  = successor->left;
           }
           if (current == presuccessor) { /*situation 1*/
                successor->left = current->right;
           }
           else { /*situation 2*/
                successor->left = current->left;
                presuccessor->left = successor->right;
                successor->right = current->right;
           }
           q = successor;
     }

     if (parent->left == current)
        parent->left = q;
     else
        parent->right = q;

     freeNode(current);
    }

    void search(node * root, int n){
    if (root == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }

    node * current = root;

    while (current != null){
        if (current->value > n) {
            current = current->left;
        }
        else if (current->value < n){
            current = current->right;
        }
        else
            printf("%d is present", n)
    }

    printf("n is missing");
}

void empty(node * root){
    if(root != NULL) {
        empty(root->left);
        empty(root->right);
        free(root);
    }
}

/* Print the value at each node with a single space character */
/* Else if tree is empty print "tree is empty" */
/* Do this for the following functions */

/*void inTraversal(node * root){
  if node == null 
    return;

  inTraversal(node.left)
  visit(node)
  inorder(node.right)
}
void preTraversal(){
  preorder(node)
  if node == null then return
  visit(node)
  preorder(node.left) 
  preorder(node.right)
}
void postTraversal(){
postorder(node)
  if node == null then return
  postorder(node.left)
  postorder(node.right)
  visit(node)
}*/

   int quit() {
    exit(1);

    return 0;
   }
```

header

```
#ifndef FUNC_H
#define FUNC_H

node * createNode(int value);
void insert(node * root, int n);
void search(node * root, int n);
void empty(node * root);
void delete(node * root, int n);
int quit();

#endif
```

Comment: The error is more silly if it doesn't tell the line number of where it occurs.

Comment: And the question tends to become _off-topic_ because __it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem__.

Comment: interesting: `node a` is not the same as `struct node a`! I hope that was not intentional?

Comment: @mah it's for the beginning of eery function so it's the entire declaration of the header file and the first line of their initialization in the functions file. So it says it everytime say "void insert(node * root, int n)" shows up... but it's for every function.

Comment: @Deduplicator What do you mean by this?

Comment: @user3362954 the problem is your "main" source file does a #include of func.h before it's defined the node type.

Comment: I meant that in your main function you define struct tag node and type node, but type node as a pointer to a struct node.

Answer (score 5):

It's probably that:

```
    node * createNode(int value);
```

`node` is unknown at that point.

Move the definition of `node` into your header file.

Comment: More than "probably"... his "main file" has a #include of func.h, which _needs_ the node type, but the type is defined in that main file only afterwards. Also his "functions file" has no access to the type definition at all.

Comment: This created a mass production of the error "request for member 'left' /'right'/'value' in something not a structure or union"

Comment: @user3362954 you cant keep dumping your compiler errors here. You get this error because node needs to be forward declared before struct node.